# ios having alignment issues of an image in an content view inside a tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom cell inside an `UITableView`. Within that custom cell I am trying to put an image and to vertically align it horizontally.  As soon as I do that I get that red line.
I have clicked the update frames button, there were no pop up of a menu to select any options.

Heres an image to get a better understanding.
What do I need to do to fix it?

[image: image of my custom cell]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraints for your image view are not sufficient for Auto Layout to know where & how big the image view should be:
Constraints for views need to specify the position (x, y) plus the size of the view (width, height).

To fix your issue, add constraints for:

1. leading
2. trailing, or width
3. top
4. bottom, or height

You could also press *Add missing constraints* in the menu that pops up when you press that `|△|` button, but I discourage you from doing so, because then it might add constraints you were not actually looking for.

Comment: Yes the add missing constraints fixes the problem and gives me what I was looking for. I would like to know how to do this manually. Is there a way to see the exact constraint that it placed? I see that it put in a leading constraint and an equal relation. Dunno what that is.

Comment: From the image it seems you have only added a center y constraint. You can see all constraints added to a view on the right side where it says **Constraints** in bold (and the graphic).

Comment: To manually add constraints, press on the little square button right next to the triangle one. Then select whichever constraints you want to add.